# Don't escape html in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

rails 3 seems to escape everything, including html.  I have tried using raw() but it still escapes html.  Is there a workaround?  This is my helper that I am using (/helpers/application_helper.rb):

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def good_time(status = true)
    res = ""
    if status == true
      res << "Status is true, with a long message attached..."
    else
      res << "Status is false, with another long message"
    end
  end
end
```

I am calling the helper in my view using this code:

```
<%= raw(good_time(true)) %>
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use `.html_safe` like this:

```
def good_time(status = true)
  if status
    "Status is true, with a long message attached...".html_safe
  else
    "Status is false, with another long message".html_safe
  end
end

<%= good_time(true) %>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I found out a way to fix it just after I posted the question, but this is much more elegant and simplistic.

Comment: Outstanding answer.  15-minute tutorials notwithstanding, it always surprises me how hard some of the most trivial tasks are in Rails.  Having a bulldozer is all well and good, but there are times all you need is a shrimp fork. :)

Comment: This only apply to rails 3 ._.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same thing and discovered a safer solution than using `html_safe`, especially once you introduce strings which are dynamic.

First, the updated code:

```
def good_time(long_message1, long_message2, status = true)
  html = "".html_safe
  html << "Status is #{status}, "
  if status
    html << long_message1
  else
    html << long_message2
  end
  html
end

<%= good_time(true) %>
```

This escapes `long_message` content if it is unsafe, but leaves it unescaped if it is safe.

This allows `"long message for success & such."` to display properly, but also escapes `"malicious message <script>alert('foo')</script>"`.

The explanation boils down to this -- `'foo'.html_safe` returns an ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer which acts like a String in every way except one: When you append a String to a SafeBuffer (by calling + or <<), that other String is HTML-escaped before it is appended to the SafeBuffer. When you append another SafeBuffer to a SafeBuffer, no escaping will occur. Rails is rendering all of your views under the hood using SafeBuffers, so the updated method above ends up providing Rails with a SafeBuffer that we've controlled to perform escaping on the `long_message` "as-needed" rather than "always".

Now, the credit for this answer goes entirely to Henning Koch, and is explained in far more detail at [Everything you know about html_safe is wrong](http://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong) -- my recap above attempts only to provide the essence of the explanation in the event that this link ever dies.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, because it will escape *all* HTML in `long_message1` and `long_message2`. The asker seems to want to allow some HTML. He can do that by calling `.html_safe` on the string, but obviously he should only do that if he can trust the string. What you're suggesting won't allow any HTML, it'll all be escaped. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Mischa This does not escape all HTML in `long_message1` and `long_message2` -- that's the whole point. :-) SafeBuffer's concatenation behavior only escapes content if it is unsafe. In my answer, I include an example with `&`, which is correctly *not* escaped, and displays as `&` (not `&amp;`). Also, if you're curious for more examples and detail, note the link to Henning Koch's full explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I have to take a deeper look at SafeBuffer. I wonder how it determines what is safe and what is not. For example, what if asker wants to have a link in his message? Would it allow that in your implementation?

Comment: Testing this, it seems any HTML tag is escaped. So it looks like my original objection is basically true: your implementation won't allow any HTML *tags*, it's all escaped.

Comment: This is what I tried: `s = ''.html_safe` and then `s << '<strong>I am bold</strong>'`, which returns `"&lt;strong&gt;I am bold&lt;/strong&gt;"`

Comment: Henning Koch says so too: "When you append a String to a SafeBuffer (by calling + or <<), that other String is HTML-escaped before it is appended to the SafeBuffer" and "When you append another SafeBuffer to a SafeBuffer, no escaping will occur". This means that to prevent escaping you'd have to call `.html_safe` on the string you're appending as well. Sorry, but your answer is wrong.