# Can't set Javascript variable to Ruby variable value

Tags: javascript, ruby

I have a Ruby variable:

```
@json = [{"lat":37.8690058,"lng":-122.2555342},{"lat":37.8739362,"lng":-122.2653001},{"lat":37.8701101,"lng":-122.2578559}]
```

When I try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

   var test = <%= @json %>
   console.log(test);

</script>
```

Firebug tells me:

```
invalid property id
var test = [{&quot;lat&quot;:37.869005...707408,&quot;lng&quot;:-122.2545767}]
```

How can I set the variable successfully?

Comment: As you can see, Rails escapes output unless you tell it not to. Try `<%= raw @json =>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your JSON quotes are being replaced with HTML entities. Try using `.html_safe`

```
var test = <%= @json.html_safe %>
```

If that doesn't solve it have a look in this other post as I'm no ruby expert,

[Don't escape html in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932267/dont-escape-html-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Huh? Well, that's why I put <%= ... %> to make it recognizable to JS. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @JonathanChen: is `@json` a string or a hash?

Comment: @tokland: I believe it is a hash.

Comment: @JonathanChen: you believe? is your code! :-) anyway, `{"key": value}` is not a Ruby Hash. `:key => value} or `key: value}` are. Check my answer, if @json a Ruby hash, you need `to_json`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming @json is a Ruby object:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var test = <%= @json.to_json.html_safe %>;
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, `.to_json` is necessary here.