# html_safe and still escaped html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

html_safe and still escaped html

I have the following reply helper:

```
def mb_reply_login post
  if current_user
    "<button data-depth='" + post.depth.to_s + "' data-post-id='" + post.id.to_s + "'  class='mb_btn mb_reply btn'>reply</button>".html_safe
  else
    ...
  end
```

and call it from within views like so:

```
<%=mb_reply_login post %>
```

However, it's return escaped html and am confused as to why? It seems like it shouldn't according to [Don't escape html in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932267/dont-escape-html-in-ruby-on-rails) and the rails api.

How would I return unenscaped html? I tried

```
"<button data-depth='" + post.depth.to_s.html_safe + "' data-post-id='" + post.id.to_s.html_safe + "'  class='mb_btn mb_reply btn'>reply</button>".html_safe
```

but no dice

thx in advance

Comment: Try this: `"<button data-depth='#{post.depth}' data-post-id='#{post.id}' class='mb_btn mb_reply btn'>reply</button>".html_safe`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you concatenate strings in Ruby on Rails, every single String that hasn't been marked as html_safe is first escaped before concatentating.

Using your second snippet, make sure to call .html_safe on every string (including the constants such as:

```
"<button data-depth='"
```

Better yet, you can use interpolation, such as:

```
"<button data-depth='#{post.depth.to_s.html_safe}' 
 data-post-id='#{post.id.to_s.html_safe}' 
 class='mb_btn mb_reply btn'>reply</button>".html_safe
```