# How do I prevent my HTML tags from getting escaped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html-escape-characters

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have this in my app/helpers/admin_helper.rb file …

```
module AdminHelper

  def menu_builder(page_id)
    tabs = ['Current Objects','Add New Object','Approve Objects']
    content = ""
    tabs.each do |tab|
      content << if page_id == tab
        content_tag('li', content_tag('a', tab, :href => nil ), :class => 'current') + " "
      else
        content_tag('li', content_tag('a', tab, :href => "/#{tab}" )) + " "
      end
    end
    content
  end

end
```

but on my view, when I invoke the method

```
<h1>Admin#index</h1>
<ul>
    <%= menu_builder(@page_id) %>
</ul>
```

The HTML is escaped instead of just rendering as tags.  That is, when I view source, this is what I see on my page …

```
<ul>

&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/Current Objects&quot;&gt;Current Objects&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/Add New Object&quot;&gt;Add New Object&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt; &lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;/Approve Objects&quot;&gt;Approve Objects&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt; 

</ul>
```

What do I need to do so that my page will render correctly?

Comment: Call `.html_safe` on `content`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't escape html in ruby on rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932267/dont-escape-html-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `menu_builder` helper method so that it returns `content.html_safe` instead of `content`.

The [`html_safe`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.6/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe) method marks a string as being safe for insertion into HTML without escaping being performed.